# Using `fs.readdir()` recursively and asynchronously, running something when finished

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I am trying to visit a tree using fs.readdir. The tricky part is that I would like the script to run something *once* when the visiting is done.

This is what I wrote -- but it's broken. I was mistakenly convinced that the end of async would be called only once, and only at the end. However, since `build()` calls itself recursively, the "end of the cycle" function is actually run several times (once for each directory).

```
  var p = require('path');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var build = exports.build = function( dirPath, cb ){

  if( typeof dirPath === 'function' ){
    cb = dirPath;
    dirPath = '.';
  }

  // Read all of the files in that directory
  fs.readdir( dirPath, function( err, fileNames ){
    if( err ) return cb( err );

    async.eachSeries(
      fileNames,
      function( fileName, cb ){

        console.log( "Found:", fileName );

        fs.lstat( p.join( dirPath, fileName ), function( err, fileStat ){
          if( err ) return cb( err );

          // It's a directory: rerun the whole thing in that directory
          if( fileStat.isDirectory() ){
            log( "File is a directory. Entering it and running" );
            return build( p.join( dirPath, fileName), cb );
          } else {
            return cb( null );
          }
        })
      },

      function( err ){
        if( err ) return cb( err );

        // PROBLEM: This will run several times
        console.log("I WANT THIS TO HAPPEN ONLY ONCE");
        cb( null );
      }
    ); // End of async cycle

  })
}

build( function( err ){
  console.log("RESULT:", err );
  process.exit();
});
```

At this point, the writing `RESULT:` is coming up at the end, but it's a fluke. If anything in the cycle takes longer than expected, process.exit() will trigger.

What's the smallest possible change to this code to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a third argument when you recursively call `build`. Then in the final callback check if that argument is undefined because you don't send this argument when you first call the function:

```
var build = exports.build = function( dirPath, cb, recursing ){

  if( typeof dirPath === 'function' ){
    cb = dirPath;
    dirPath = '.';
  }

  // Read all of the files in that directory
  fs.readdir( dirPath, function( err, fileNames){
    if( err ) return cb( err );

    async.eachSeries(
      fileNames,
      function( fileName, cb ){

        console.log( "Found:", fileName );

        fs.lstat( p.join( dirPath, fileName ), function( err, fileStat ){
          if( err ) return cb( err );

          // It's a directory: rerun the whole thing in that directory
          if( fileStat.isDirectory() ){
            console.log( "File is a directory. Entering it and running" );
            return build( p.join( dirPath, fileName), cb, true );
          } else {
            return cb( null );
          }
        })
      },

      function( err ){
        if( err ) return cb( err );

        // PROBLEM: This will run several times
        if(recursing)
          cb(null)
        else{
          console.log("I WANT THIS TO HAPPEN ONLY ONCE");
          cb( null );
        }
      }
    ); // End of async cycle

  })
}
```